# Menubar application for Mac with circle amount

Tags: objective-c

I have started to learn Objective-c and thought it would be kinda cool to create a menubar app. I got all that working but was wondering how apps like mint put a circle with a number in it like mint does here:
http://cl.ly/image/3j2n1A2I2u2q

Is that a built in feature of NSStatusBar? Or are they doing it some other way?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely it's using a custom view for the status bar item: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSStatusBar class and setup icon like this:

```
-(void)setupIcon:(NSString*)resourcePath {
    if (self.statusItem == nil) {
        self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];

        //Loads an image as resource
        NSImage * img = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath] autorelease];

        if (img == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Could not create image: %@.", resourcePath);
        } else {
            [self.statusItem setImage:img];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a custom view is probably better solution if you need to add a number.